# $x_n^3- y_n^3 \rightarrow 0 \ as \ n \rightarrow \infty$, then $x_n- y_n \rightarrow 0 $ if

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Consider two real valued sequences $\{x_n\} and \{y_n\}$ satisfying the condition $x_n^3- y_n^3 \rightarrow 0 \ as \ n \rightarrow \infty$, then

(A) $x_n- y_n \rightarrow 0 $

(B) $x_n- y_n \rightarrow 0 $  only if  $\{x_n\}$ converges

(C) $x_n- y_n \rightarrow 0 $  only if  $\{|x_n|-|y_n|\}$ converges

(D) $x_n- y_n \rightarrow 0 $  only if  $\{|x_n^2 +x_ny_n+y_n^2|\}$ converges

As suggested in the answer (d) may not be necessarily true, and additionally I can eliminate (b).

Answer (score 1):

it's not d since for $x_n=y_n=n$ it is $x_n-y_n=0\to0$ and $x_n^2+x_ny_n+y_n^2=3n^2\to\infty$

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: d implies that if $x_n-y_n\to0$ then $|x_n^2+x_ny_n+y_n^2|$  converges. But I gave a counterexample

Comment: Can you provide the solution to the problem

Comment: Maybe it is c since $|x_n-y_n|\ge ||x_n|-|y_n||$

Comment: Can you help me with the solution